# Java Binary Reading Object

Tags: java, binaryfiles

I have stored a group of 4 students in ArrayList, and they each have unique ID that is generated upon creation. Example: [James, 1], [Jone, 2], 
[Kate, 3], [Jack, 4]. However if I read those objects from Binary File, then add additional Person objects into the array list, the ID is reset to 0. But I want to new objects ID to append such as: [Sam, 5].

```
private int id;
private static int count;

public Student(String firstName, String lastName, String phone, String address) {
        super();
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        id = ++count;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.address = address;
}

public void loadPersonBinary(){
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        ObjectInputStream ois = null;
        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream("Person.dat");
            ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch(Exception ev) {
            System.out.println("Exception!");
        }
        System.out.println("Reading from the file...");
        try {
            p = (ArrayList<Person>) ois.readObject();
            //it only read once. Count always stays at 1
            int count = 0;
            Person.setCount(++count);
            System.out.println(count);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
        } 
        try {
            ois.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Assuming it was an ArrayList that was written to file, the readObject will read in the entire array.  Don't see any loop, so count will always be 1 in this case.  Not sure what you are expecting.

Comment: You have 4 people stored in 1 `ArrayList`. You read in the list, then increase the `personCount`. You do not actually access the people from the list. It's as if your code says "1 list represents 1 person"

Answer (score 0):

you must serialize your datas:

1 you must declare public Person implements Serializable

2 better declare a version UID (not mandatory)

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 354054054054L;
```

3 just write as you did

```
List< Person> the_list;
OutputStream file = new FileOutputStream( "mydatas.ser" );
OutputStream buffer = new BufferedOutputStream( file );
ObjectOutput output = new ObjectOutputStream( buffer );
output.writeObject(the_list);
```

4 and you can reload it

```
 InputStream file2 = new FileInputStream( "mydatas.ser" );
 InputStream buffer2 = new BufferedInputStream( file2 );
 ObjectInput input = new ObjectInputStream ( buffer2 );
 ArrayList< Person> lp= (ArrayList< Person>)  input.readObject();
```

Comment: He's not trying to output a `Student` object. I suggest you read the question again

Comment: thanks, it's a Person. I change my code. I Suppose Student is as subclass of Person

Answer (score 0):

When you are writing to the file using `ObjectOutPutStream->FileOutputStream`, you have to use different API to append.

```
 ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("person.dat",true));
```

Have a look at FileOutputStream from [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html)

```
public FileOutputStream(String name,
                boolean append)
                 throws FileNotFoundException
```

> Creates a file output stream to write to the file with the specified name. If the second argument is true, then bytes will be written to the end of the file rather than the beginning. A new FileDescriptor object is created to represent this file connection.

Personally, I too prefer writing List and reading List of objects instead of writing multiple individual objects.